# Setting labels on axis ticks in D3 V5

Tags: d3.js, graph

I'm trying to set the x-axis labels to date strings I create.  I tried using scaleTime() but found that to be a nightmare and not really required for what I want to do.

I've tried scaleLinear() and scaleOrdinal() with 'almost' success, but didn't get there totally

In the examples below 'xlabels' is an array of about 23 strings, like:
["02 JAN 2020", "03 JAN 2020" ... etc]

First trying scaleLinear:

```
   function draw_Xscale() {
      var xScale1 = d3.scaleLinear()
              .domain([0, xlabels.length])
              .range([0, width]);

      const g = svg.append("g")
              .attr("class", "axis")
              .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height - 10})`);

      let x_axis = d3.axisBottom(xScale1).ticks(tlabels.length);
      g.call(x_axis).selectAll("line,path").style("stroke", "brown");
   }
```

This draws an axis but the tick labels are numbers [0 .. 22] - not what I want.  I tried stuff from some online examples something like the following tacked on:

```
      .selectAll("text")    
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", ".15em")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)");
```

but simply couldnt get it to work - probably some subtlety of the syntax I don't understand.

I also tried scaleOrdinal:

```
   function draw_OrdScale() {
      let arr = Array.from({length: xlabels.length}, (e, i) => i);

      var ordinalScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
         .domain(xlabels)
         .range([0, width]);

      const g = svg.append("g")
         .attr("class", "axis")
         .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height-100})`);

      let x_axis = d3.axisBottom(ordinalScale).ticks(tlabels.length);
      g.call(x_axis).selectAll("line,path").style("stroke", "brown");
   }
```

This drew an axis with the labels I specified, but half of them were piled up on top of each other on the left and the other half on the right.  Obviously I have the range wrong but not sure what it wants to be.  I tried setting the range to:

```
.range([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22]);
```

But this just had them a scrunched up into a black smear on the left.

I spent most of the day looking for examples of what I want to do but the few that looked like they should work, didn't.

TIA for any insights

Comment: Have you tried scaleBand? that should work

Answer (score 0):

We're going to try to make the scale a bit more generic, in case you have more data.

Suppose that `data` is an array of objects, with a `date` property. The first step is to get the date to an usable state:

```
function toTitleCase(str) {
    return str.replace(/[^-'\s]+/g, function(word) {
        return word.replace(/^./, function(first) {
        return first.toUpperCase();
        });
    });
}

var data = data.map(d => toTitleCase(d.date.toLowerCase()))
```

This will convert every date from "02 JAN 2020" to "02 Jan 2020".

Afterwards, we need to use [a date parser](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format). This will convert every date to a real date object:

```
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d %b %Y");
data = data.map(d => parseTime(d.date);
```

Finally, we can now use a time scale, using [`d3.extent()`](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-extent) to find the min and max value in your dataset. `d3.extent()` will return an array with two values, the min and the max, and it works on dates, like the rest of D3:

```
d3
  .scaleTime()
  .domain(d3.extent(d => d.date))
  .nice() // Make the scale look prettier.
```

That'll give you a scale that works automatically with any date and will work as you add more values.